# GlobalPayments HPP 508

Tags: .net, global-payments-api

I'm trying to integrate Global Payments HPP to my website.

I followed the instruction on the developer portal on how to setup HPP using .NET but every time I try to access the HPP page, I get "508 Invalid data in MERCHANT_ID field. Please contact the merchant". I'm able to use the API using the same credential. Am I missing something?

Comment: Any update on this - I get the same.  Tried sanitising data, manually generating the hash etc - but nothing seems to work..